# MS SQL Server and JDBC: closed connection

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

Im getting

> **I/O Error: DB server closed connection.**

while connecting to MS SQL server 2008 from java code .

---

SQL server is in mixed mode and its in local machine.My connection string is
**jTDS**

> **jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://machineName:1433;databaseName=DB;integratedSecurity=true**

---

stack trace is

> java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: DB server closed connection.
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2311)
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:610)
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.(ConnectionJDBC2.java:345)
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at com.app.hibernate.test.(test.java:22)
>       at com.app.hibernate.test.main(test.java:53)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: DB server closed connection.
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.readPacket(SharedSocket.java:848)
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.getNetPacket(SharedSocket.java:727)
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.getPacket(ResponseStream.java:466)
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ResponseStream.read(ResponseStream.java:103)
>       at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2206)
>       ... 8 more
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.app.hibernate.test.db(test.java:36)
>       at com.app.hibernate.test.main(test.java:54)

**JDBC Driver**

> String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://machine:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=db";

stacktrace

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'username'.
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:156)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:240)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:78)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2636)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2046)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2034)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4003)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1550)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1207)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(SQLServerConnection.java:1054)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:758)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at com.app.hibernate.test.(test.java:22)
>       at com.app.hibernate.test.main(test.java:53)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.app.hibernate.test.db(test.java:36)
>       at com.app.hibernate.test.main(test.java:54)

Comment: can you paste stacktrace here ?

Comment: could be a server configuration issue...

Comment: i added the stacktrace with question

Comment: what could be the server config issue..

Comment: is it a remote server? if that's the case, server could be configured to not allow remote connections. Also User privileges on Database?

Comment: you mean it's hosted on the same machine that runs the code?

Comment: Try Using jdbc driver for sql server instead of jtds. Also you have to make changes to the the URL of the SQL connection. In particular, the usename needed to be in the following format user@[instanceID].

Comment: In the connection URL i mentioned the instance value.

Comment: But i can able to access the system tables.

Answer (score 4):

Your Connection String and authentication have errors. if it is mix mode don't use **SQL authentication**

Try this

PC Name       **: janaka-pc** SQL User Name **: sa** SQL Password
**: 1234** Database        **: Janak_DB**

**Code for sql Conncetion in JDBC**

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://janaka-PC;user=sa;password=1234;database=Janak_DB");

Answer (score 2):

You have problems in your connection strings

For jTDS:

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://machineName:1433;databaseName=DB;**useNTLMv2=tru‌​e;domain=workgroup**

You may read http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#windowsAuth for the required Single-Sign-On library for NTLM to work.

"integratedSecurity=true" that you supplied for jdts is valid when using the JDBC driver

jdbc:sqlserver://machine:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=db;**integratedSecurity=true**

Comment: I used both the URL but while in SQL server drive   **Cannot open database "DB" requested by the login. The login failed.** While jtds **The USENTLMV2 connection property is invalid.**

Comment: If im setting **useNTLMv2=false** them im getting same login failed error.

Comment: But i can able to access the system tables in DB

Comment: For the jdts case, did you install (copy) the ntmlauth.dll file? You may read about it in the [readme.sso](http://jtds.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jtds/branches/jTDS%201.2%20%28stable%29/README.SSO?revision=1120&view=markup)

Comment: To my knowledge there are two choices: either 1-) the dll file is not in a directory referenced by the PATH environment variable (I hope that you are sure that PATH contains jre dir  2-) your server is not ntlmV2 ready; in that case you may try **jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://machineName:1433;databaseName=DB;** as connection string dropping the useNTLMv2 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have an authentication error in on the MS SQL side.

If you're not in control of how to adquire the connection (ie, you're using a Datasource or a Connection Pool), the connection URL must contain the login and password to be used, like:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://machine:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=db;user=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD";
```

If the application is running on a Windows machine and you want to use the credentials of the logged user, then you can specify the `domain` parameter with or without `useNTLMv2`.

Finally, if you are on a windows machine but you want to authenticate the user against a domain, then you must supply the username, password and domain parameters. You can read all about it in the [jtds FAQ](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html), specially the [URL Format](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat) section.