# SQL connection exception

Tags: java, sql-server

The below error throwing while connecting sqlserver(java). I don't know root cause of this problem.

```
CONNECTION URL :: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<IP>:<port>/DB2011;instance=TESTINST 


Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Connection reset 
   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2277) 
   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:599) 
   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:331)
   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:178) 
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) 
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

If anyone face this problem, kindly let us know, how can solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MS SQL Server and JDBC: closed connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225398/ms-sql-server-and-jdbc-closed-connection)

Comment: @JonSkeet i saw the link which u have mentioned. it is something different(Login failed).

Comment: There are two stack traces there - one is login failed, the other is a closed connection.

Comment: @JonSkeet Neither of them is a 'connection reset'.

Comment: can you give more information as to when this happens? Like at the start of the application or if when you reach a certain load?

Answer (score 1):

I got this exception some time ago because the server couldn't handle more connections. A restart of the database fixed this.

Another time the problem was a firewall between my laptop and the database server. The firewall had to allow my IP to pass.