# Getting "db server closed connection" when connecting with MS SQL server

Tags: android, sql-server, jtds

In my android app, I am connecting MS SQL server using a jtds jar file. below is the code for my connection class:

```
public class ConnectionClass {
    String ip = "192.168.1.26";

    //String ip = "IRFAN//SQLPOS";

    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "Sysit";
    String un = "sa";
    String password = "123";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            Log.d("connection url",ConnURL);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.d("connection variable",conn.toString());
        return conn;
    }
}
```

I am able to connect to database by creating the object of connectinclass and calling the `CONN()`. I am connecting to database the same way in 2 or 3 activities. but after few clicks in the app, the database connection is not working.

It shows following error in the LogCat:

> E/ERRO: I/O Error: DB server closed connection.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225398/ms-sql-server-and-jdbc-closed-connection

Comment: did you try closing the connection after it's been used?